# Javascript form validation alert

Tags: javascript

Here is the HTML

```
<input class="btn" onClick="return IsEmpty()" type="submit" name='submit' value="submit"/>
```

The javascript

```
function IsEmpty(){
  if(document.forms['form'].name.value == "")
  {
    alert("empty");
    return false;
  }
  if(document.forms['form'].name.value != ""){
    alert('Thank You, Your order is being processed');
    return true;
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is get the thank you alert to show only if all fields are filled out. Currently, the form catches the missing input but still alerts the thank you message.

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sa1omp23/1/

Comment: but the second `if` is not required - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sa1omp23/2/

Comment: I put the second if there trying to get the alert to stop, I know it shouldn't be needed but it still is not working. After seeing it work in other peoples fiddle I know the issue must be somewhere else, thank you to everyone who answered the question for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```js
function IsEmpty(){
  if(document.forms['form'].name.value == "")
  {
    alert("empty");
    return false;
  }
  if(document.forms['form'].name.value != ""){
    alert('Thank You, Your order is being processed');
    return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="form" action="">
    <input name="name" />
    <input class="btn" onClick="return IsEmpty()" type="submit" name='submit' value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Please try this :**

```
    function IsEmpty() {
        if (document.forms['form'].name.value == "") {
            alert("empty");
            return false;
        }
        alert('Thank You, Your order is being processed');
        return true;
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/sa1omp23/5/)